# Android preload a url into WebView while splashscreen is showing

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I have an app with a splash-screen which after a few seconds opens up the main activity that has a WebView.  The problem is that, only then, does the main activity start to load the URL, which sometimes take several seconds.  It seems silly for the double wait.  However, my attempts to pre-load the WebView have been less then successful.

The essence of the issue is that the splash screen and main activity are two different activities and the WebView is resource bound (layout) to the main activity.  Copying the WebView (webview2=webview1) doesn't work, not surprisingly.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow these steps..

1) set splash layout on your screen.

2) start a new thread, in this thread inflate a layout that contains webview.

3) Load url in webView. Set webview Client to webview to know when your page loading completes. [There is a quick example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). override onPageFinished.

4) Now break the thread and pass this inflated view to next activity, and set it to setContentView(inflatedView);

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying out your suggestion, however, when I try to inflate inside the thread, it throws an obtuse exception (Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView).  Later in the stack trace, something more informative is this:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()  Never seen that before..


Comment: Make a Handler and call a handler from that thread. you cant access UI elements from thread oter than UI thread. or do all stuff in ui thread. You will have to look for a work around.

Comment: This works nicely now.  The page still takes too long to load though. ;)

Comment: I have a question: At point 4) how do you pass the inflated view from one activity to the next?

Answer (score 0):

make a layout with a spash screen ABOVE your webview and setVisibility to View.GONE after X seconds. if you load the webview on onCreate it will be loaded behind the splash, and when the splash screen disapears you have a already loaded Webview :)