# Android: splash screen and webview

Tags: android, multithreading, webview, screen, splash-screen

I've trying for days now to get a solution to show a splash screen while loading a webview.

I've looked around and there are several approaches: 
- make activity just to show splash screen, wait a few seconds and then start the webview activity -> this is not a solution since all the loading is again done after splash screen is closed

- second approach is something like this:

  ```
     myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); 
  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         findViewById(R.id.webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         //hide loading image
         findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
         //show webview
        }
      });
  ```

  This works, but again there is a slight appearance of a white screen while transitioning to webview. And also you can't control the timing of your splash screen.
- third solution is something that I'd like to make, but (even after few days of searching and trying) don't know how -> show splash screen in one thread, prepare everything for a webview in another and then simply switch to webview.

My question is, can anybody show me where to start with this third solution?

- I wanted to try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592091/android-preload-a-url-into-webview-while-splashscreen-is-showing)! but I couldn't figure out how to pass webview to another activity and from what I read, this is not even a good idea.

Any suggestion, ideas, pointers? Is there a way to show splash screen, prepare(inflate) webview in another thread and then switch to it after loading url (and everything else) is done?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a WebChromeClient on the Webview. In the WebChromeClient, you have a method onProgressChange.

You can do disappear the splash screen when the onProgressChange tell you that the page are finish to load.

Edit:
You can call in a thread your Url with HttpGet for example and retrieve the response. When you have the response you can load the webview with the loadData(...) method.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but as I said, I'd like to use third solution, with a thread loading webview in the background. I wonder it that is possible and how it can be done. I know that this what you suggest would be enough, but I really want to know how to do this with another approach...

Comment: You can call in a thread your Url with HttpGet for example and retrieve the response. When you have the response you can load the webview with the loadData(...) method.